# How to change Vaadin 7 layout based on Combobox items selection?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

For example, if I've three items and I want to change the layout based on item selected in the combo box...how do I achieve that? Here is my sample code:

```
ComboBox combo = new ComboBox("My combo box");
combo.addItems("item 1", "item 2", "item 3");
combo.setTextInputAllowed(false);
combo.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
combo.select("item 1");
combo.setImmediate(true);
combo.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
/**
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
Notification.show("Selected item: " + event.getProperty().getValue(), Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
}
});
ExampleGrid grid = new ExampleGrid();
grid.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
Panel panel = new Panel(grid);
panel.setSizeFull();
addComponent(panel);
```

So there are three panels created for three items in the combo box. But, I don't know how to change the layout based on item selected inside a combo box?

Of course, I can get the first panel easily. But, I want to see all three panels based on combo box selection.

Answer (score 0):

Keep hold of your panels there and correlate them to the items.  E.g. use an Enum and store the correlation in a Map.  Add a value change listener to the combobox and setVisisble(false/true) on the panels according to the selection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Using enum and storing correlation in a map, I've done. But, the problem with this approach is that the layout of the combobox somehow floats below ( it hangs like a fruit in a tree). Here is a code snippet that I use:

`LinkedHashMap<EnumType, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<EnumType, String>();`
        `map.put(EnumType.ENUM1, "Enum1 Caption");`
        `ComboBox box = new ComboBox("Box", ContainerUtils.createContainerFromMap(map));`    `box.setItemCaptionMode(ComboBox.ITEM_CAPTION_MODE_PROPERTY);`

Comment: i am pretty sure, that layout problems are not the result of using enum or not. if this helped make your code going, please accept the answer.  if you have further questions, that do not directly concern the original question, please start a new one (SO is a QA site and no forum) or add the relevant code/screenshots as an edit to the original question, if you think the problems go hand in hand.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough points to mark "This answer is useful" buttton here. But, I thank you for your suggestion. Your suggestions are useful, anyway. ;)